# Lists and multiprocessing in python

Tags: python

I'm experiencing some weird python problems during multiprocessing. Here is a simplified python program illustrating the problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


varcol = {"list": []}


def addelement(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(1)


addelement(varcol)
print(len(varcol["list"]))


def addelement_mp(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(2)
    print(len(varcol["list"]))


p = Process(target=addelement_mp, args=(varcol,))
p.start()

time.sleep(5)
print(len(varcol["list"]))
```

I'd like to know why the output of the above python program is:

```
1
2
1
```

instead of:

```
1
2
2
```

Comment: are you sure that you're getting 1,2,1 as the output?

Comment: What OS are you on? There are some significant differences in the out-of-the-box multiprocessing behaviour between Windows and non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @VanPeer Yes definitely... I tried it just now. It is rather strange. It is as if the list is just being copied and passed to the subprocess by value instead of by reference.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm on linux Mint... the latest version. I have since done some workaround to accomplish what I was doing. But I did waste quite a lot of time trying to figure out why Python had this unexpected behaviour. Anyway I believe the proper python way is to use a manager.list.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a new process, python use `fork()`, which creates a child process with exact same data as the parent process, but these data locate at different addresses. Consider this code to see the effect of `fork()` on variable addresses (tested on Windows 10, python 3.6):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


def addelement_mp(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(2)
    print('multiprocess address: -----')
    print(hex(id(varcol)))
    print('multiprocess address ended -----')

def addelement(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    varcol = {"list": []}

    addelement(varcol)
    print(hex(id(varcol)))


    p = Process(target=addelement_mp, args=(varcol,))
    p.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    print(hex(id(varcol)))
```

Example output:

```
0x18d0aa39af8
multiprocess address: -----
0x10f074f2a20
multiprocess address ended -----
0x18d0aa39af8
```

So, as you can see, what the child process is modifying is NOT the same object as your main process.

Comment: This is incorrect. Python does *not* use fork on Windows, because Windows doesn't provide a fork operation. See the multiprocessing documentation for more.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't look into how Python implement it in Windows, I just briefly modify that code on my windows machine. However, regardless of the implementation details, the same concept applies: the child process has its own memory space, which explains the different addresses.

Comment: Thanks @TuanDT You may be right... in fact with subsequent reading I found that there is a manager.list which is to be used for things like this.

Answer (score -1):

When you use multiprocessing to open a second process, an entirely new instance of Python, with its own global state, is created. That global state is not shared, so changes made by child processes to global variables will be invisible to the parent process

Use Multi-Threading instead of multi-Processing, if you wanna share variable between different processes.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

varcol = {"list": []}


def addelement(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(1)


addelement(varcol)
print(len(varcol["list"]))


def addelement_mp(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(2)
    print(len(varcol["list"]))


p = Thread(target=addelement_mp, args=(varcol,))
p.start()

time.sleep(1)
print(len(varcol["list"]))
```

Or You can try using callback function

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

varcol = {"list": []}


def addelement(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(1)


addelement(varcol)
print(len(varcol["list"]))   # Always print 1


def addelement_mp(varcol):
    varcol["list"].append(2)
    print(len(varcol["list"]))
    return varcol


def confirm_len(varcol):
    print(len(varcol[0]["list"]))


pool=Pool()
# Will First Call addelement_mp and then call confirm_len with addelement_mp return value as its argv.
r = pool.map_async(addelement_mp, (varcol,), callback=confirm_len)
r.wait()
```

if you don't wanna create a new callback function then you can do multiprocessing using multiprocessing.Pool.map

```
print len(pool.map(addelement_mp, [varcol])[0]["list"])
```

Comment: OP was asking why the code behave this way, not what to modify the code for any purposes. P/S it wasn't me who voted down. Just FYI.

Comment: @van-peer yes because changes made by child processes to global variables will be invisible